# make gvim treat wrapped line as new line

Tags: vim, line-breaks, word-wrap

When I press "j" or arrow down in vim/gvim the cursor moves to the next line. which is good for writing code.

When writing text however the lines are usually much longer then the text with. Therefore I can not easily get the word just above THIS word. So in almost all editors and text processors pressing the up arrow HERE ↑ would put the cursor in front of "word". But in gvim the cursor moves to the blank line between "code." and "When".

I use wrap (set: wrap) and linebreak (set: lbr).

With all the power of vim - this has to be straight forward?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

<kbd>g</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> and <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> move up/down by visual line instead of text line.  You could map <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> to these using

```
noremap j gj
noremap k gk
```

Some people prefer to only setup those maps for specific filetypes, in which case you'd want something like

```
au FileType html,tex noremap <buffer> j gj
au FileType html,tex noremap <buffer> k gk
```

Comment: This is freaking excellent. Thank you for that excellent and thorough answer. If I could accept twice.... Oh - btw: the mappings go in .vimrc right?

Comment: @StephenPaulger: I learned that from someone else using it on SO too. :)

@Andreas: Correct.

Comment: Andreas - yes put them in .vimrc

Comment: Hey, how would you add "text" filetype (so .txt for example)

Comment: @mrkva: `:help new-filetype` will describe how you can add new filetypes.

Comment: I have also added `nnoremap ga g^a` and `nnoremap gA g$a` to be able to add text in the beginning/end of visual lines. The same could be done for i/I.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much. I used `<Up>` and `<Down>` instead of `j` and `k` and now my `vim` works more or less like notepad